# How to clear DBMS_OUTPUT with a command

Tags: plsql, toad, dbms-output

I tried with:

clear screen (not work)

[image]

Comment: is this SQL Developer or PLSQL Developer?

Comment: Are you sure you mean clear? Blank screen means "clear" sometimes... Is it "flush", "display"? Be more specific when describing what you want.

Comment: clear, clean, fresh, remove comments... about DBMS_OUTPUT, with a COMMAND into block BEGIN

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to clear a toad `DBMS Output` screen using `clear screen` command. Unfortunately, tools like toad are not supporting all the `SQLPLUS` command. You can use `clear screen` command when you are logged in with `SQLPLUS`. See below ways to clear the screen

```
SQL> clear screen
```

which can also be shortened to

```
SQL> cl scr
```

And you can also use:

```
SQL> host clear
```

Or

```
SQL> ho clear
```

For your toad , in the `DBMS Output` tab there is first button right to `watch`, is used to clear the output of buffer.

Comment: @J.Chomel He looked confused with Toad and SQLPLUS

Comment: I used all, only Toad recognize  the word "clear" , the others not are recognize. But when I try with clear screen I get this error: (PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SCREEN" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;). In my begin want put this clean window, I have a big log, and I need refresh.

Comment: @delive `the others not are recognize` what are others here ? Also can you show how are you using clear in toad. I told you a button to click in toad to clear the buffer . Did you try that ,

Comment: @XING the button works correctly, and F7 to clear DBMS_OUTPUT, but I need a command, to clean automatically.

Comment: @delive In toad you cannot use the command. Toad is a tool which doesnot support these commands.  These command are meant for `SQLPLUS`

Comment: Hi  XING, can you put this in your post ? " you cannot use the command. Toad is a tool which doesnot support these commands" Thanks.

Comment: @delive Why you unaccepted the answer. Did it not work for you or is there something you didnot understand ?

Comment: because it does not solve the problem I had, I do not think it's convenient to accept your answer, when I was marked negative. that is, they mark me negative and I have to accept an invalid answer? I think not.

Comment: Then why you accepted it earlier. It took so many months for tou to understand that solution didnot work for you. Anyways...

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
dbms_output.enable(100000);
```

Keep in mind that you'll only see results once your PL/SQL block is over. It's not immediate to see result from Oracle PL/SQL during execution. You may try something like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105043/6019417).

Comment: @J.Chomel OP question is more about tool oriented. From Toad for Oracle he is trying to run `clear screen` which will never work. Not sure if your answer really fits what he needs

Comment: @XING, yeah, too bad for me, I don't have Toad anymore so can't test  a thing.

Comment: @J. Chomel, I tried in my BEGIN block, and not work, I want say, not clean the window DBMS_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

We can use enable/disable option of DBMS_OUTPUT to either keep **DBMS_OUTPUT** Console clean or print the instructions you wanted to be passed.

For a sample code

```
Begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.DISABLE;
```

--code you want to ignore

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HI');
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case clear screen is not working in that case you can use:
SQL> host clear

Watch this video in case of any confusion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyUZNHcUdY8

Comment: any affiliation with the channel of the linked video?