# Command to know execution flow while the PL/SQL block is running?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

As part my project I had run a `PL/SQL` block to process more than 13,00,000 records from 12 different tables.

To know the execution flow I have already included `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` command.

My requirement is to know the execution flow while the block is still running and the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` only displays the flow after PL/SQL block execution.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
PL/SQL Block;
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any way to flush output from PL/SQL in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472587/is-there-any-way-to-flush-output-from-pl-sql-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a dedicated logging table and AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION you could also use package [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003).

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('Starting at '||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Starting procedure');

   ... some PL/SQL code

   -- If you like you can set intermediate updates at any time:
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Still running...');

   ... some more PL/SQL code

   ... at the end you may reset application info 
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
END;
```

While procedure is running you can query information by

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#, USERNAME, OSUSER, MODULE, ACTION
from V$SESSION
where USERNAME = ...;
```

Comment: I don't have access to update the Procedure as this is a production activity in my project.