# Oracle SQLPLUS: immediately flush SPOOL output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am logging my SQLPLUS session to a file.

```
SPOOL mylog.txt
```

But if I doing commands with a short output

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

it is not immediately put into the file. It takes some commands. If it is a command with a large output it happens instantly.

So I think it is some sort of buffer that needs to be filled before writing to the file.

I tried

```
SET FLUSH ON
```

but is did not do the trick.

How can I tell SPOOL to flush the buffer immediately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to flush output from PL/SQL in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472587/is-there-any-way-to-flush-output-from-pl-sql-in-oracle)

Comment: Hi, Maybe you can watch for Oracle's [utl_file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (as far as I can tell).

Data is spooled in chunks of 8K (*typically*, as Ask Tom says) so, until you fill the buffer (or issue `spool off`), you won't see anything.