# Not getting expected output in cursor by iterations

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are trying to insert around 1.5 million records using PL/Sql in loop in chunk of 50,000 records. We also want to write output on console as soon as 1 iteration of loop is completed. As we are loading in chunk of 50000 records, I am hoping it would write 30 times on the console. But, in my case, it just giving me status **after all cycle of loop** is completed, just not sure why it's not printing the result as soon as one cycle of loop is completed. Logging is very crucial for our process. Please suggest.

**Query :**

```
 --- business logic--
LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Starting Loop - '|| Counter );
     FETCH PRSQ_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO PRSQ_EXT LIMIT 50000;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total Number of Records to be Inserted ' || PRSQ_CURSOR%ROWCOUNT);

      BEGIN
         FORALL i IN 1 .. PRSQ_EXT.COUNT
            INSERT INTO FSG_WRK.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA_BKP0915
                 VALUES (
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).PR_ID,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).AD_ID,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).AD_TYPE,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).AD_DT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_DT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_ITEM,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_DT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_DT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_DT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VSRC,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_IND,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VRSL,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VER_NAME,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_VMTH,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_COMMENT,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).SQ_LOCK_TOKEN,
                 PRSQ_EXT(i).XR_SOURCE_ID
                 );
         COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error Inserting Records into table- '|| SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 100) || SQLCODE );
   END;
   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Ending Loop - '|| Counter );
   Counter := Counter+1 ;
   
 EXIT WHEN PRSQ_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE PRSQ_CURSOR;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Script Execution Finished- '|| SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

I am getting expected output but when whole process got completed :

```
Starting Script Execution - 15-SEP-20 03.23.04.822577000 AM -05:00
Starting Loop - 1
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 50000
Ending Loop - 1
Starting Loop - 2
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 100000
Ending Loop - 2
Starting Loop - 3
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 150000
Ending Loop - 3
Starting Loop - 4
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 200000
Ending Loop - 4
Starting Loop - 5
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 250000
Ending Loop - 5
Starting Loop - 6
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 300000
Ending Loop - 6
Starting Loop - 7
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 350000
Ending Loop - 7
Starting Loop - 8
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 400000
Ending Loop - 8
Starting Loop - 9
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 450000
Ending Loop - 9
Starting Loop - 10
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 500000
Ending Loop - 10
Starting Loop - 11
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 550000
Ending Loop - 11
Starting Loop - 12
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 600000
Ending Loop - 12
Starting Loop - 13
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 650000
Ending Loop - 13
Starting Loop - 14
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 700000
Ending Loop - 14
Starting Loop - 15
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 750000
Ending Loop - 15
Starting Loop - 16
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 800000
Ending Loop - 16
Starting Loop - 17
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 850000
Ending Loop - 17
Starting Loop - 18
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 900000
Ending Loop - 18
Starting Loop - 19
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 950000
Ending Loop - 19
Starting Loop - 20
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1000000
Ending Loop - 20
Starting Loop - 21
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1050000
Ending Loop - 21
Starting Loop - 22
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1100000
Ending Loop - 22
Starting Loop - 23
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1150000
Ending Loop - 23
Starting Loop - 24
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1200000
Ending Loop - 24
Starting Loop - 25
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1250000
Ending Loop - 25
Starting Loop - 26
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1300000
Ending Loop - 26
Starting Loop - 27
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1350000
Ending Loop - 27
Starting Loop - 28
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1400000
Ending Loop - 28
Starting Loop - 29
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1450000
Ending Loop - 29
Starting Loop - 30
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1500000
Ending Loop - 30
Starting Loop - 31
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1550000
Ending Loop - 31
Starting Loop - 32
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1600000
Ending Loop - 32
Starting Loop - 33
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1650000
Ending Loop - 33
Starting Loop - 34
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1700000
Ending Loop - 34
Starting Loop - 35
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1750000
Ending Loop - 35
Starting Loop - 36
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1800000
Ending Loop - 36
Starting Loop - 37
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1850000
Ending Loop - 37
Starting Loop - 38
Total Number of Records to be Inserted 1866217
Ending Loop - 38
Script Execution Finished- 15-SEP-20 03.49.19.842459000 AM -05:00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Total Record- 1866217
Start Time  - 15-SEP-20 03.23.04.822577000 AM -05:00
End Time    - 15-SEP-20 03.49.19.842459000 AM -05:00
```

Comment: This question seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472587/is-there-any-way-to-flush-output-from-pl-sql-in-oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to flush output from PL/SQL in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472587/is-there-any-way-to-flush-output-from-pl-sql-in-oracle)