# How to redirect 'dbms_output.put_line content' to log file from a TimesTen Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, timesten

See the sample Timesten procedure below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(employee_id IN NUMBER) AS
salary NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT emp_sal INTO salary FROM employee where emp_id = employee_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Id:' || employee_id || ' Annual Income:' || salary*12);
END;
/
```

If I call the procedure from Command line interface(ttisql), dbms_output.put_line logs gets printed there only.
But I want to collect such debug logs to somewhere else in a log file. Whenever procedure get executed it should append these content to a file. Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling your procedure from ttisql as you've said you can use **spool filepath** and **spool off** to log any messages appeared on the screen. To append new information to the already existed log file just use **APPEND** option after **filepath**

```
spool c:\logfile.log append
```

Comment: No, I am not planning to call it from ttisql.. I am going to trigger this procedure from c++ code..

Comment: then in addition to @Candie answer take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453538/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-dbms-output-put-line-to-a-file

Comment: Yeah, i already gone through this question. But it works fine for Oracle. My stored procedure is in TimesTen, not in Oracle.

Comment: TimesTen also has UTL_FILE package http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21645/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF

Comment: Great !! Thanks, TimesTen has this support from 11.2.2 release. I was using older one.. Hence I was not able to use UTL_FILE package.