# Pl sql procedure dbms output

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Is there anyway we can write/capture the dbms outputs in a log file? I have a procedure run from the program and it has dbms in it.. Where the output will be saved when executed? Please guide

Comment: You need to put an example of your code. Your question , without it, is too vague.

Comment: Put `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;`before the `declare` statement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453538/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-dbms-output-put-line-to-a-file

Comment: What kind of program are you calling the procedure from? If it isn't something that supports this natively. e.g. via `set serveroutput on`, you'd need to extract the buffered output - it's stored in a buffer as the docs say, not saved in a table. ([This is one way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19143017/266304), but it really depends on your client and what you want to do next).

Comment: Worse stuff man is that you could have easily find the answer, just by typing your question on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said you'll have to include a `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` statement before  your `DECLARE` but you'll also need to handle the output on the OS level:
`sqlplus -s user/pword@db '@script.sql;' > log.txt`
Hint: the `-s` flag will hide the sqlplus version info from your log file.

Answer (score 2):

Put `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;`before the `declare` statement

Answer (score 2):

You need use **SET SERVEROUTPUT ON**

```
set serveroutput on
begin
dbms_output.put_line('something to write')
end;
```

Comment: May i know where in server, these logs will be written