# Viewing DBMS Output when package is called by SOA

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, soa

Hi I am looking to be able to see DBMS_OUTPUT from my package when it is called from SOA. I have tried setting serveroutput to on but that does not do anything.

The current set up is that I am sending a SOAP UI request to SOA which calls a service which in turn then calls my database package. I have several DBMS OUPTUT statements within this package but I have no idea how to view these messages. I am currently using SQL Developer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Write to a logging table.

Comment: OK I will use a logging table. Thank you!

Comment: If you think some of those error messages might be relevant to the caller of your SOA service, you can send them in the service response (instead of or in addition to logging them via DBMS_OUTPUT / logging table)

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_OUTPUT package can help us achieve this.

Tom Kyte has shown how to do it in Java.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845

Here is another example of the same work but writing to a file instead.
[How to redirect the output of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453538/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-dbms-output-put-line-to-a-file)

Both are using same package DBMS_OUTPUT to achieve this.